# Can't access SQL server database from ASP.net application running on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012, remote-connection

i've read every thread i've found online related to this issue(and followed the steps they showed) and i cant' still access the database; it keeps throwing the "refused remote connection" error, It is kind of weird because i can browse through the database on the "server explorer" tab on Visual Studio (and that is remote accesing also, shouldn't that fail too?) do you have any ideas? thanks.

Comment: <connectionStrings>

    <add name="ConnPuiPui" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=puipuiDB;Integrated Security=True" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Are you sure SQL Server is a default instance and not a named instance?

Comment: Nope. How can i do that?

Comment: You need to check in SQL Server Configuration Manager if the instance is named `MSSQLSERVER` or something else like `SQLEXPRESS`. If it is not `MSSQLSERVER` then your connection string needs to say `localhost\instancename`.

Comment: Sorry, I can't find a field for the instance nam on SQLSCM, could you please guide me through it? Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XiFES.png